# How do I remove two same elements from a JSONArray?

Tags: android, json, listview

I can parse json and list it with listview.

I want to remove two same elements from json and I just want to list one.

the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Product> arrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ReadJSON().execute(url);
            }
        });
    }

    class ReadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return readURL(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String content) {
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
                JSONArray jsonArray =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("School");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray server = c.getJSONArray("Names");
                    for(int j=0; j<server.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject serverObject = server.getJSONObject(j);

                        arrayList.add(new Product(
                                serverObject.getString("id"),
                                serverObject.getString("name")
                        ));
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            NewtAdapter adapter = new NewtAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list, arrayList
            );
            ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

json file:

```
{
    "School":[
        {
            "Names":[
                    {"id":"1", "name":"John"},
                    {"id":"2", "name":"Amanda"},
                    {"id":"3", "name":"Robert"},
                    {"id":"4", "name":"Jackie"},
                    {"id":"5", "name":"Palma"},
                    {"id":"1", "name":"Walcott"}
                ]
        }
    ]
}
```

output:

1 - John

---

2 - Amanda

---

3 - Robert

---

4 - Jackie

---

5 - Palma

---

1 - Walcott

I want to remove ids that are the same and just want to list one.

output should be like this:

1 - John

---

2 - Amanda

---

3 - Robert

---

4 - Jackie

---

5 - Palma

How Can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Use a `Set` of `Object`. Or with `ArrayList` you can check for duplicate item before adding new one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Product class has a getId() method, modify your code, from this:

```
for(int j=0; j<server.length(); j++){
    JSONObject serverObject = server.getJSONObject(j);

    arrayList.add(new Product(
        serverObject.getString("id"),
        serverObject.getString("name")
    ));
}
```

to this:

```
for(int j=0; j<server.length(); j++){
    JSONObject serverObject = server.getJSONObject(j);

    boolean alreadyInList = false;
    for (Product p : arrayList) {
        if (p.getId().equals(serverObject.getString("id")))
            alreadyInList = true;
    }

    if (!alreadyInList)
        arrayList.add(new Product(
            serverObject.getString("id"),
            serverObject.getString("name")
        ));
}
```

basically, before you add the new item in your list, you check if there already is something with the same id.

Comment: Nice - it would be more concise if an additional assumption could be made that the Product class implements 'equals' using its "id" so that the 'alreadyInList' logic can be replaced by arrayList.contains().

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
outer:
for(int j=0; j<server.length(); j++)  {         
   JSONObject serverObject = server.getJSONObject(j);
   for(Product product : arrayList) {
         if(product.getId().equals(serverObject.getString("id")))
                 continue outer;
   }

  arrayList.add(new Product(serverObject.getString("id"), serverObject.getString("name") ));
}
```

Comment: Whats the issue ?? @JackNc

Comment: the continue in here is related to the inner foreach loop, so it won't interrupt the outer loop execution